# Fabric CA not started after starting Hyperledger

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to get the End-to-End demo for Hyperledger from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qxfuWVz7jRA

The current steps I have done up so far:
1. Git clone the fabric-sdk-java
2. Resolve the dependencies
3. Run `docker-compose up -d --force-recreate`
4. Run the End2endIT.java file as demonstrated in the video

However, I am stuck at the stage where it fails at this exception:
`org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.EnrollmentException: Failed to enroll user admin` ...
`Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)`

My guess is that the fabric CA is not working properly given that I don't see the CA in the list when I run `docker ps -a`

[image: docker ps -a result]

Anyone familiar with Fabric/Docker/Hyperledger can help shed some light?

Answer (score 0):

`docker logs ca_contaner_name`

Check why your ca container doesn't work.